# Unable to change keyboard layout on lock screen

Tags: login-screen, 19.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 and now I have two issues.

1. I have two layouts. Login screen displays "EN" every time (and sometimes it not true).
2. I am not able to change keyboard layout on login screen